# Difference between "vederti uccidere" and "vederti ucciso"

Tags: difference, tenses

> Non voglio **vederti uccidere** proprio ora.
>
> Non voglio **vederti ucciso** proprio ora.

I assume that they both mean "I don't want to see you killed now", but what is the difference between using Infinitivo and Participio passato?

Incidentally, I wonder if the Infinitivo version can also mean "see you kill (somebody)" if a direct object follows "uccidere"?

Answer (score 2):

The former can have another meaning:

> Non voglio vederti uccidere (qualcuno) proprio ora.

I don't want to see you kill (somebody) now.

The use of participio passato states that I don't want to see you killed now by someone else.

Comment: Hi. If you use a pronoun like "lo" instead, do you say "Non voglio vederti uccider**lo** (or: uccider**la**)"?

Comment: @Alone-zee: Yes, it's that way.